# overflow: scroll is not working in my electron app

Tags: css

[my cord in inspector browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWZrv.png)

[screen with that it doesn't scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpp5K.png)

css https://hastebin.com/yavuzejuzo.css

code typed out because images are not that good

```
<body>
    <main data-reactroot>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="chat">
                <div id="chat-text">
                    <p>Text 1</p>
                    <p>Text 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" id="text-input-light" placeholder="Send a message">
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

It does create a box with those scrolling bars but I can't actually scroll it. How to fix this?

Comment: does the content inside the box overflow? if not then it will not scroll

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will make things easier for those trying to help you and increase your chances of quickly getting a solution to your problem.

Comment: it does overflow a fixed div @pete

Comment: Please edit your question and create a [mcve] then as we are unable to help you with what you have provided

Comment: okay, @Pete like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions.

**First solution: Setting `height` to parent containers**

```
html, body, .content {
  height:100%;
}
```

**Second solution: Using viewport size**

```
#chat-text {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

In this solution, the `div` will take 50% of the viewport height. More on this can be found at [CSSTricks](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/).

**Edit 1:** Using your code, it works for me. When adding the login-box `div`, that is when you get the issue because it takes 100% of the width and height and is on top of the chat box. For `#login-box.hidden`, change from:

```
#login-box.hidden {
  display: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

to:

```
#login-box.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

`display: hidden;` is not a valid CSS rule.

Comment: it won't work. it doesn't scroll still. Give me a moment I'll add more code.

Comment: I added all the code now. I hope it doesn't make it unclear to you

Comment: @RSG Edited my answer.

Comment: ah k thanks I just remembered that the login box was hidden over it